# How to create a JSON file for use in UITableView

Tags: ios, json, uitableview

How to create a JSON file for use in a UITableView, so you can remote the TableView from the web?

Comment: Creating a JSON file is simple: open a text editor, paste/type some JSON data in it, then save it with ASCII or Unicode encoding.

Comment: Yeah, but how do I code it so it fits for the UITableView? Btw, I don't know JSON- language...

Comment: you can't format your JSON to directly work in a TableView.. When you grabbed the JSON just like always put the info over the table view delegate methods on the tableview

Comment: [UITableView Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html) - if there's something you don't understand, or try and can't make work, ask a specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating JSON is simple.

Start with:

```
{
    "somename": [
```

Then add contents to it like this:

```
      {
        "title": "Test",
        "identifier": "1",
      },
      {
        "title": "Test2",
        "identifier": "2",
      }
```

Finish off with:

```
      }
    ]
}
```

You can do this in any text editor.

Comment: Thanks! But how do I connect the items to the UITableView? I've come so far that I've made a UITableView which gets data from iTunes Top 10 albums, but the problem is that I want to make a list of something else...

Comment: What's the URL of the iTunes Top 10 JSON file, also JSON is pretty easy and you don't need to comply with allot of things like in other languages. Allot is accepted in JSON.

Comment: No, I don't want to use the iTunes Top 10 list, I want to create my own list using JSON...

Comment: Like I said, if you can give me the URL I can see how the structure is  and show you how you can change it..

Comment: Oh, I see! It's https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topalbums/limit=10/json

Comment: I see, just a plain JSON file. You need to edit your xcode project and change a couple of things, first of all you need to edit the project and look for the values that are inserted in your App based on the JSON code, I think you must see something like: `label` `im:name` etc.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood me... I just used the iTunes to learn how to implement a JSON file in UITableView, so I just want to change the JSON file to another which has the data that I want it to contain... It's just a text label on each table cell I want to create...
Can't I use the iTunes Top 10 JSON file as an template and just change the titles?

Comment: You can, like I said. Check the values for `cell.textlabel =` and use that in your JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I think I found my solution, I just need a server that supports JSON, and then everything is perfect! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Downloading data from the web is pretty simple.  You can use `NSURLConnection` to asynchronously download a JSON payload from the web.  To make things simple though, you could just download an existing payload from the web and drop it in your project.  This is a JSON payload for some Beatles albums from the iTunes store API:

https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=136975&entity=album

But JSON isn't enough: You need to get that JSON data converted to a native data structure: `NSDictionary`/`NSArray`.  You can do this with the `NSJSONSerialization` class:

```
NSData *jsonData; // however you got your JSON data
NSError *jsonError = nil;
NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                                           options:0
                                                             error:&jsonError];

self.items = items[@"results"];
[self.tableview reloadData]; // reload your tableview to refresh it with the data
```

This example is going to vary slightly based on the exact structure of your JSON payload, but I'll leave that as an exercise for you to read about [in the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

As far as how `UITableView` works, I'd read up on [Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html)